# Mozilla JavaScript debugger can't edit

Tags: javascript, debugging, mozilla

It was okay all the time, but today I noticed that I cannot edit website's javascript code in mozilla's debugger anymore. Maybe there is an option to disable editing and I accidentally pressed it? Thanks for help.

Comment: You can use JS console in the browser but you can't modify the source files.

Comment: yes that's what I meant, I used to be able to edit the JS files until you refresh the page